# How does SUSY avoid to create non-Lorentz interactions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, feynman-diagrams

A three-legs fermion interaction or boson absorbing a fermion are things we do not see in QFT because the corresponding terms in the Lagrangian are not Lorentz invariant.

But in susy, naively, such terms could happen if we transform from the corresponding well behaved terms, say a three bosons diagram or a fermion absorbing a boson. Still, the Lagrangian keeps being Lorentz-Invariant after a SUSY transformation.

So the possible not invariant terms are never generated, or so they cancel somehow? Is it a general mechanism? How does it work, for instance, for the interactions of the MSSM?

Comment: Perhaps a good enough answer could be to use the superparticle formalism and expand a superparticle 3-legs vertex to show why the non-Lorentz terms do not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just substitute fermions for bosons to determine the SUSY equivalent of a given interaction.  For example, the kinetic terms for the bosons and fermions look quite different--first order in derivatives for the fermions, versus second order for bosons.  As another example, the SUSY equivalent of a four-boson interaction is a Yukawa interaction ( a fermion-antifermion-boson vertex).  Using the full SUSY transformation, you never generate vertices with odd numbers of fermions/antifermions.

Comment: What about the fermion-boson-boson vertex in the MSSM? Does it never generate a boson-fermion-fermion?

Comment: There are no vertices with odd numbers of fermions in any quantum field theory.  Moreover, the SUSY equivalent of boson-fermion-fermion is, as I said above, a four-boson vertex.

Comment: Sorry, I told it in reverse. Is there some emoticon for embarrassed?

Comment: Hmm sorry I was not paying atention... so you really say that a four boson becomes a Yukawa? Fascinating.

Comment: That is correct.  Generally, an n-boson vertex becomes a vertex with (n/2 - 1) bosons and fermion-antifermion pair.  So a four-boson vertex becomes Yukawa, and a boson mass term (a two-particle vertex) becomes a fermion mass term.